# Are these component values and functions proper for this device given its datasheet?

Tags: digital-logic

Im planning to use this[H11L1M-Opto](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/H11L1M-185291.pdf) IC with the following circuit:

[image]

Vin is around 5V 20Hz pulse coming after a LP filter to the opto device as shown above.
The specs says 1.6mA is enough for turn ON so I set it to 2mA. So for that I set the R1 to 1.8k since the voltage drop at 2mA is 1.1V then R1=(5-1.1)/2 = 1.8k. I added R2 for a floating input as 100k. Vo will drive a logic input.

If the values for R1 and R2 are reasonable, I have two questions:

1) Vcc is 5V; so what should be the resistor value for R3 which is an open collector resistor? I chose it 100k, can it be any value that Vcc can handle? I cannot see any recommendation in the datasheet.

2) Do I need a decoupling capacitor C1 like 100nF between Vcc and GND like in an opamp?

Comment: Whats going on with the 330 Ω resistor? You form a series circuit with 330 Ω + R1 + LED

Comment: Oh I see. You are putting the input signal through a LP filter. You'll need to buffer the signal or you form a series circuit as mentioned above.

Comment: I dont think I need to buffer I can always lower R1 to 1.5k for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optocoupler does not have a high-impedance input, and requires a current to flow to turn on, so you do not need to protect against a floating input.

The pull-up resistor, together with the parasitic capacitances of a few pF, forms an RC circuit. You would need 280 Ω to get 1 Mbit/s out of this chip, but if speed does not matter, increase the resistor to save power. As shown in the datasheet of a clone (PC900), you are not expected to use more than 10 kΩ:

[image: Sharp PC900 rise/fall time vs. load resistance]

The H11L1 datasheet does not mention a decoupling capacitor, and does not even have it in the test circuit. However, you *are* doing digital switching, so I'd rather add one.

Comment: Thank you  I tried with 22k it works maybe it is because my freq is only 32Hz. What woul you recommend for 32Hz and 512Hz? Would 10k be fine? I dont wanna load so much thanks

Comment: 5 V / 10 kΩ = 0.5 mA. That isn't much of a load; and compare with the chip's supply current. Anyway, if your receiving device can tolerate slow edges on its input, there's no problem with using larger resistors.